# How do I do conditional array arithmetic on a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to get a better grip on numpy arrays, so I have a sample question to ask about them:

Say I have a numpy array called a. I want to perform an operation on a that increments all the values inside it that are less than 0 and leaves the rest alone. for example, if I had:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,-1,-2,-3])
```

I would want to return:

```
([1,2,3,0,-1,-2])
```

What is the most compact syntax for this?

Thanks!

Comment: for a readable tutorial, see http://scipy.org/Cookbook/Indexing

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
In [45]: a = np.array([1,2,3,-1,-2,-3])

In [46]: a[a<0]+=1

In [47]: a
Out[47]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  0, -1, -2])
```

Answer (score 12):

To mutate it:

```
a[a<0] += 1
```

To leave the original array alone:

```
a + (a<0)
```