# numpy: concise conditional syntax for array division

Tags: python, syntax, numpy

Assume a simple 1-dimensional numpy array:

```
>>> x = np.array([1,3,5,0,3,2])
```

Now assume I want to perform the operation `1.0/x`.  I can do this with numpy:

```
>>> 1.0/x
array([ 1.        ,  0.33333333,  0.2       ,         inf,  0.33333333,
    0.5       ])
```

The problem here is the infinity (`inf`) result for the original element value 0, because `1.0/0` seems to return infinity in place of undefined behaviour.

Instead of infinity, I would like to provide my own custom value where these divide by 0 scenarios arise.  While I know this can be accomplished using a loop, I would like to know whether there is any kind of idiomatic syntax for this kind of operation.

There's a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409255/how-do-i-do-conditional-array-arithmetic-on-a-numpy-array), but it only deals with the *if something: (do this) else: (do nothing)* scenario whereas my question is a *if something: (do this) else: (do that)* scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always patch it up later:

```
a = 1.0/x
inf_ind = np.isinf(a)
a[inf_ind] = your_value
```

or

```
a[inf_ind] = f(x[inf_ind])
```

Which has the advantage of not getting in the way of the nice optimized numpy methods.

Answer (score 3):

Building on the previous answer, you can also set floating point callback modes to detect when you need to apply the inf transform.

I can't find a callback that gets called on each floating point error, however.

See also: 
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html

```
import numpy
class IsDivideError(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hasDivideError=False

    def callback(self, x,y):
        self.hasDivideError=True

ide=IsDivideError()
numpy.seterr(divide='call')
numpy.seterrcall(lambda x,y: ide.callback(x,y) )
x = numpy.array([1,3,5,0,3,2])
val=1.0/x
if(ide.hasDivideError):
    val[numpy.isinf(val)]=5
```