# exchanging values of 2 maps 2D arrays in ipython,

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-loops

I'm a beginner in python, and I wrote a code:

```
g=rand_image
for i in range(100):
    for j in range (100):
        G = np.fft.fft2(g)
        theta = angle(G)
        G_prim = image ** 0.5 * exp(1j * theta)
        g_prim = np.fft.ifft2(G_prim)
        for k in range(300):
            for l in range(300):
                if g_prim[k, l].imag > 1e-8 or g_prim[k, l] < 0:
                    g[k,l]=g[k,l]-(2-0.02*i)*g_prim[k,l]
                else:
                    g[k ,l] = g_prim[k,l]
```

where I compare 2 images, rand_image and image. It takes 2hours to run such code. I would like to make it faster somehow replacing the 2 loops in the bottom (comparing 2 images with 300px*300px size) with maybe a map of 2 pictures and replacing certain values? Although I'm not sure if that is possible.

I nead to increment value of i and run the code multiple times for each i value.

Comment: you should get rid at least of the inner loop, research conditional assignment with numpy array. Or at least cycle only trough a list of indices that do meet the condition. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409255/how-do-i-do-conditional-array-arithmetic-on-a-numpy-array

Comment: That is not very useful because I do not do a simple action like adding independent value to the elements that meet special criteria. I actually have to have the coordinates of those elements (pixels to be precise) so that I can compare those elements to the elements of the same coordinates from the second picture: g[k,l]=g[k,l]-(2-0.02*i)*g_prim[k,l]

Comment: What is ```theta```? a scaler? and ```image```?

Comment: ```g[k,l]``` gets *over written* multiple times for different values of ```i,j``` - is that what you intended?,  That looks like a hugh waste of meaningless calcs.   is the ```k,l``` loop indented correctly?

Comment: theta is a phase of a complex number.

Comment: How many dimensions does ```theta``` have?

Comment: The closer I look at your code and my answer, I get the impression that your solution is not doing what you want it to do and the problem you are trying to solve is not clear.  Please take some time to write a *verbal* description of what you are trying to accomplish - like a specification - then add it to your question.  That will help us and it will probably help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
                              ^ ^
for i in range(100):          | |
    for j in range (100):     | |
        G = np.fft.fft2(g) #--- |
        theta = angle(G) #-------
```

The first two statements in the *`j`* suite do not make use of `i` or `j` so move them out of the loops.

---

```
            if g_prim[k, l].imag > 1e-8 or g_prim[k, l] < 0:
                g[k,l]=g[k,l]-(2-0.02*i)*g_prim[k,l]
            else:
                g = g_prim
```

In this innermost loop suite you repeatedly assign different values to individual *pixels* of `g` if the condition is met.

- g_prim relies on `j` so the condition ONLY relies on `j`
- the calculation in the suite ONLY relies on `i`.

The value assigned makes use of the outermost loop's value, `i` but the condition does NOT. For every `j` that results in a True condition there will be 100 `i`'s.

- if the condition is met when `j` equals two then there will be one-hundred `i,j` pairs that meet the condition - (0,2), (1,2), ... (99,2)
- each iteration of the `k,l` loop(s) will assign to `g[k,l]` when the condition is met.
- the only `i` that matters is when `i` equals 99 because it will overwrite each previous calc when `j` was two.

The net affect is that only the terminal value (99) of `i` matters.  You are doing a lot of wasted operations.

To make matters worse if the condition is not met, you overwrite ALL previous individual assignments making them useless.

It actually looks as if the entire outer loop is superfluous and can be discarded - `i` isn't used anywhere except that conditional suite - `g[k,l]=g[k,l]-(2-0.02*i)*g_prim[k,l]`.

If your example is faithfully presented, the inner two (`k,l`) loops can be replaced using [boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) as @nio suggested.

Make a mask that represents your condition and its *inverse*

```
mask = np.logical_or(g_prim.imag > 1e-8, g_prim < 0)
not_mask = np.logical_not(mask)
```

Use the mask to make the assignments when the condition is met

```
#(2-0.02*i) .. i = 99!!
k = 2 - .02 * 99
g[mask] = g[mask] - k*g_prim[mask]
```

Assuming you did NOT intend to overwrite the previous conditional assignment,
use the inverse mask to make the rest of the assignments.

```
g[not_mask] = g_prim[not_mask]
```

Comment: i is used to calculate g, which is used to calculate theta (phase) and theta changes slowly. I will try with mask, that may make things faster. I'm not sure though what can I do with j. What I do with j now is I change those elements of g that meet condition and then I do "j" loop and check again if they transformed well or if I have to put the physical constraints on them and run again. What I discovered is that if there is no j loop or few iteration, it doesn't work properly.  And you are right of course, I didnt copy that, I want to make final "else" condition g[k,l]=g_prim[k,l]

Comment: The only place ```i``` is used is in ```g[k,l]=g[k,l]-(2-0.02*i)*g_prim[k,l]```

Comment: @Leukonoe what is ```pow_spec_img```? what datatype is it? how many dimensions is it?