# Numpy Error using 'np.arange': Index Error

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am working with the code shown below and am getting an Index Error:

> index 8 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 8  and
>
> index 6 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6`.

When changing `np.arrange(1,9)` and `np.arrange(2,8)` to `np.arrange(8)` and `np.arrange(6)` respectively the code runs with no errors. However, the output matrix C is giving different results than expected. What if I want `i` and `j` to be an integer with values (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) instead of (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7) and `k` and `l` with integer values (2,3,4,5,6,7)? I am creating a matrix C which looks at the inner 6x6 square of B (ignoring the border) and uses the matrix D as a 'weight' when determining the values of matrix C.

```
import numpy
import numpy as np


A = np.matrix([[8,8,8,7,7,6,8,2],
               [8,8,7,7,7,6,6,7],
               [1,8,8,7,7,6,6,6],
               [1,1,8,7,7,6,7,7],
               [1,1,1,1,8,7,7,6],
               [1,1,2,1,8,7,7,6],
               [2,2,2,1,1,8,7,7],
               [2,1,2,1,1,8,8,7]])


B = np.ones((8,8),dtype=np.int)

for i in np.arange(1,9):
    for j in np.arange(1,9):
        B[i,j] = A[i,j]

C = np.zeros((6,6),dtype=np.int)
print C

D = np.matrix([[1,1,2,3,3,2,2,1],
               [1,2,1,2,3,3,3,2],
               [1,1,2,1,1,2,2,3],
               [2,2,3,2,2,2,1,3],
               [1,2,2,3,2,3,1,3],
               [1,2,3,3,2,3,2,3],
               [1,2,2,3,2,3,1,2],
               [2,2,3,2,2,3,2,2]])
print D

for k in np.arange(2,8):
    for l in np.arange(2,8):


            B[k,l] # point in middle
            b = B[(k-1),(l-1)]
            if b == 8:
                # Matrix C is smaller than Matrix B
                C[(k-1),(l-1)] = C[(k-1),(l-1)] + 1*D[(k-1),(l-1)]
```

Comment: numpy and python use zero-based indexing not 1-based indexing so index 8 is out of bounds. You likely want `np.arange(8)` or more robustly: `i in np.arange(A.shape[0])` and `j in np.arange(A.shape[1])`

Comment: This was literally brought up [in your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36080741/670206) so I'm not sure where the confusion is.

Comment: The text above this question is different and substantially clearer than the `duplicate`. I moved my answer to the `duplicate`, but my answer references the text in this question.

Comment: I'd be happy to remove the `duplicate` if it would help.  But I think OP is not taking serious the idea that indexes must fall in the correct range, here `[0,8)`.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Python indexing starts at 0, not 1, so your array would be from 0-7, not 1-8.