# (Python) How to use conditional statements on every element of array using [:] syntax?

Tags: python, arrays, conditional-statements

If i need to ask a condition on every element of a numpy.ndarray of integers, do I have to use a for loop

```
for i in range(n):
    if a[i] == 0:
        a[i] = 1
```

or can I ask the question using [:] syntax

```
if a[:] == 0:
    #...
```

I know the previous is wrong, but is there any way of doing something similar?

Comment: What is `#...` supposed to do. Do you want to call a code fragment for every element?

Comment: List comprehension would work here depending on what you want to do

Comment: Do you have a *list* or an *array*?

Comment: What is the type of `a`? Python array or numpy array?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem for example, if an element if bigger than 1, then assign 1 to that element, for every element

Comment: Edit: is a ndarray of integers

Comment: @JuanIgnacio Ah, so it's a Numpy array?

Comment: @ChristianDean yes, I made an edit because my question wasnt clear enough

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do conditional array arithmetic on a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409255/how-do-i-do-conditional-array-arithmetic-on-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=all#all) builtin function to accomplish what your asking:

```
all(i == 0 for i in a)
```

**Example:**

```
>>> a = [1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0]
>>> all(i == 0 for i in a)
False
```

Note however that behinds the scenes, `all` still uses a for loop. [It's just implemented in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#L283):

```c
for (;;) {
    item = iternext(it);
    if (item == NULL)
        break;
    cmp = PyObject_IsTrue(item);
    Py_DECREF(item);
    if (cmp < 0) {
        Py_DECREF(it);
        return NULL;
    }
    if (cmp == 0) {
        Py_DECREF(it);
        Py_RETURN_FALSE;
    }
```

**EDIT**: Given your most recent edits, what you probably want instead is to use a list comprehension with the ternary operator:

```
[1 if  i == 0 else i for i in a]
```

**Example:**

```
>>> a = [1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0]
>>> [1 if  i == 0 else i for i in a]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Comment: Hmmm... I don't think this actually does what the OP is asking.  Looks like the OP wants to do an operation on each element of an array, not check for the truthiness of everything.  The OP either needs to do list comprehensions with conditionals or vectorized numpy operations.

Comment: Nice use of the ternary in the list comp!  +1, even though at first it was hard for me to read because my brain expects the `if` to come later.

Comment: @CodyPiersall Thanks. But now that the OP has update their question, your solution is clearly the better one! You have my up-vote.

Comment: @ChristianDean Thanks for answering anyways, I realised my question wasnt clear enough

Comment: Glad to help out, @Juan.

Answer (score 5):

For testing a condition on every element of a numpy.ndarray **at once**, as the title could suggest:

use numpy's [`np.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) for that:

```python
if np.all(a == 0):
    # ...
```

Despite it is not lazy, `np.all` is vectorized and very fast

```python
# arrays of zeros

>>> a = np.zeros((1000000))
>>> %timeit np.all(a == 0)                    # vectorized, very fast 
10000 loops, best of 3: 34.5 µs per loop

>>>%timeit all(i == 0 for i in a)             # not vectorized...
100 loops, best of 3: 19.3 ms per loop


# arrays of non-zeros

>>> b = np.ones((1000000))
>>> %timeit np.all(b == 0)                    # not lazy, iterates through all array
1000 loops, best of 3: 498 µs per loop

>>> %timeit all(i == 0 for i in b)            # lazy, return false at first 1
1000000 loops, best of 3: 561 ns per loop


# n-D arrays of zeros

>>> c = a.reshape((100, 1000))                # 2D array
>>> %timeit np.all(c == 0)
10000 loops, best of 3: 34.7 µs per loop      # works on n-dim arrays

>>> %timeit all(i == 0 for i in c)            # wors for a 1D arrays only
...
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

---

For testing a condition on every element of a numpy.ndarray **iteratively**:

```python
for i in range(n):
    if a[i] == 0:
        a[i] = 1
```

can be replaced by `np.where`

```python
a = np.where(a == 0, 1, a)  # set value '1' where condition is met
```

---

EDIT: precisions according to the OP's comments

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `a` is your array, and you want to change values of `a` that are greater than 1 to be equal to 1:

```
a[a > 1] = 1
```

This works because the expression `a > 1` creates a [mask array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays), and when a mask array is used as an index (which it is here), the operation only applies on the `True` indices.

Comment: this is the logical answer except it should be `a[a == 0] = 1`.  All the other answers are unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 You're right according to the original question, but I was basing this example off of a comment by the OP on the OP's question.

Comment: OK I see that now.  This has to be a dupe.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Well to be fair, the OP has edited their question quite extensively. When my answer and several others were posted, it was not clear that the OP was using NumPy, or even what they really wanted. See the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45848612/1).

Comment: You can see I am a newbie at this, I thought my question was clear enough, and it didnt matter what was done inside the "if" statement, or if I used a NumPy array

Comment: @Juanig what does matter is what you want to achieve. Is it result of test if your array consists only zeros, or you want to map all zeros to ones; moreover it really does matter what kind of data sructure do you use: is it python list or numpy array

Comment: No problem @Juanig, you gotta start somewhere.  For the record, if you are using numpy arrays, my answer is the recommended way to do it.  If you are using normal lists, the last part of Christian's answer is the way to go.  Numpy arrays are generally much, much faster than using lists.  *Much* faster.  And the code is usually more readable too.

Answer (score 2):

if you need not just check, but map all 0 --> 1, use `map`:

```
map(lambda x: 1 if x==0 else x, a)
```