# How to do something conditionally with numpy matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to apply a function to cells of matrix selected by a boolean mask. That is, instead writing:

```
#given numpy arrays a[dimX][dimY], mask[dimX][dimY]

for i in range(dimX):
     for j in range(dimY):
         if(mask[i, j]):
             a[i, j] +=1
```

I'd like to do it possibly with one command operating directly within numpy.

My general target is to speed up a simulation, and I am clueless how to apply complex, conditional (like above) function to global matrix. (For curious ones, I try to implement airflow by Boltzmann Lattice Method). Motivation is I've only recently how huge difference time-wise it makes to use numpy commands instead of iterating over a matrix.

If the answer is not simple, I'd be grateful for linking to some materials tackling problem in greater detail.

Comment: `a[mask] += 1`. There's gotta be a duplicate around here somewhere, but searching for this kind of thing is hard.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409255/how-do-i-do-conditional-array-arithmetic-on-a-numpy-array) is the best dupe target I've found so far.

Comment: Also see the [NumPy indexing docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do conditional array arithmetic on a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409255/how-do-i-do-conditional-array-arithmetic-on-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.where() :

```
a = np.where(mask > 0, a + 1, a)
```